# Can an SSD notify the hosting OS that its wear level is getting high?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssd

I read a lot about SSDs and I am interested in them for server use. My biggest concern is their reliability. A lot of writes shortens their life span. I can mitigate this problem if I can run some kind of diagnostics on a regular basis on the SSD or if the SSD can automatically warn the OS that its reliability is reaching a critical level. Think of this as S.M.A.R.T or software like SpinRite for SSDs.

Does anything I mentioned exist now? Which kind/brand of SSD does this?

I don't mind swapping out a tired SSD for a newer one once a while. I am pretty sure that SSDs life is calculated in years and not in few months? For me, the improved performance will pay for the SSD over and over. I am planning to use plenty of RAM as well.

Answer (score 4):

Intel SSDs (and others) offer wear information via SMART

```
smartctl -a /dev/ssd
```

results in something like:

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH 
...cut...
232 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail
233 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age
```

with Intel SSDs, 232 is available space (0-100) and 233 is the wear indicator (0-100, lower is worse)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly enterprise class SSDs alert when they're on their way out, I know this because we killed quite a few different brands/models in testing for SQL use.

Answer (score 0):

SSD's do have various ways of telling how healthy the *think* they are. **But I wouldn't trust that information much.**

The realities are that SSD wear has little real-world testing right now. The flash cells are well tested, the algorithms well understood, but systems-level experience from real world use isn't available yet. It's being generated by the early adopters as we speak.

*The best you can do is probably to run the vendor maintenance software on a regular basis, and proactively replace the SSD well before its expected service life.*

For Intel SSDs the maintenance tool is the [SSD Toolbox](http://www.intel.com/go/ssdtoolbox/).